# Default return value for Spring map

Tags: java, spring

How do I set a default value for a util:map in the spring framework?

example:
If I pass "thisThing" I would like it to go to value-ref "call_to_default".

```
<util:map id= "someID" map-class="org.apache.commons.collections4.map">
    <constructor-arg value= "call_to_default"/>
    <entry key="someStuff" value-ref="call_to_someStuff">
```

I am not looking to pass it "default" though, I would like to pass it anything except "someStuff" and have it call default call. The code equivalent would be using getOrDefault method. I would like to do this in spring though.

Is this possible? How do I accomplish this?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? Your question is too vague

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in Spring, I'm afraid.

That said, in Java 8, Maps have a `getOrDefault` method which does what you're describing.  So if you specify a default value as a different property of your bean (the bean that uses the map, for clarity), you can integrate it with this method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can pass anything to the bean, it's just a static definition the you can reference